# Should I upgrade to 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS about 2 weeks ago. A week later a newer LTS came out. Now I know that I will get to upgrade in June but I don't know if I should upgrade or not. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: We can not anwser this for you. Either is fine.

Comment: Well i mean will it f up my laptop

Comment: Im a new user to linux/ubuntu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is about when to upgrade and understanding Ubuntu versions (Releases)

LTS releases are designed to be stable platforms that you can stick with for a long time. Ubuntu guarantees LTS releases will receive security updates and other bug fixes as well as hardware support improvements for five years. The current LTS release, **Ubuntu 14.04, will be supported until April 2019**.

In comparison, a regular release will only be supported for nine months. Considering new versions of Ubuntu are released every six months, you’ll have three months after a new version is released to upgrade to it or you won’t receive security patches anymore.

[image]

**You’ll probably want to upgrade to every LTS version — new LTS versions are released every two years. If you stick with the LTS version, you’ll still get a new Ubuntu release every two years.**

LTS versions are designed to be more polished, while the standard releases bring you the latest features that may not be completely finished yet.

**When you use the latest release, you’ll end up upgrading every six to nine months. When you use the LTS version, you can upgrade every two years or even hold on for five years.**

Thus, You should use Ubuntu LTS version for long-term-support latest version to meet latest features, (My advice is to use LTS to LTS version every two years!)

> *Hope this answer helpful to know about Ubuntu releases for new*
>   *users(Welcome!) to Ubuntu.*

Comment: Thnx for the tip i guess when i get to upgrade i will ubgrade for sure

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upgrade in June, considering that Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ends support in 26 April 2017. During this time, you will still get security updates from the Ubuntu developers (as well as for packages downloaded and installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre).

With that said, upgrading your Ubuntu computer will usually take a few hours and you will need to check the screen every so often if dialogs comes up.

IMO, if you want to upgrade, you should wait for a few weeks until the new Ubuntu release becomes more stable as more bugs are fixed.

If you want the features in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [(which you can look at this page here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases), then I suggest upgrading it.

Comment: Well i want new features and performance n stuff n things so i think i will upgrade in a month or so