# upgrading Ubuntu version on version

Tags: upgrade

I have already upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 but my question is why should I do this. As an user of this wonderful OS, what could be the consequences of not to upgrading the Ubuntu version in the future.

Comment: Here is an image with when releases go end of life http://askubuntu.com/questions/456232/should-i-upgrade-to-14-04lts  That's the only reason that forces you to upgrade: Canonical does not want to allocate resources to maintaining older versions. Upgrading will ensure security updates keep comming to your system. All other reasons (like newer software) are a matter of personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your usage patterns. Newer versions of Ubuntu typically mean: newer kernels, newer versions of unity, newer versions of the tools in the repository.

From a "conservative" point of view, you might prefer to avoid upgrades. If your system is running fine (for you); and you do not need newer versions of a certain tool - there is not much gain in moving forward. Although there is only a small chance for upgrades to fail and cause damage to your system - it is still possible; therefore: "if it is not broken, dont fix it".

The important fact is that you should understand when a version of Ubuntu runs out of support - after that, there won't be security updates, ...

The other dimension is: some people just like to run "latest-greatest". This means that you might enjoy newer features earlier than other users - but it can also mean that you have to deal with bugs that other users do not see.

Answer (score 0):

12.04 will retain its support until April 2017, so you could keep 12.04 until then and still receive security and hardware compatibility updates and bug fixes. After that point you put your machine at risk of security vulnerabilities and you may not be able to use newer hardware coming out, so it would make good sense to upgrade to 14.04 and receive updates well into 2019.

The motivation for upgrading right now would be to utilize the new features introduced in a stable version that you will likely be switching to down the road anyways, so you may as well get used to them now.