# Should I upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my PC because Windows is quite laggy on it. I want to know whether I should upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.

My system specs are :

```
Memory: 2GB
Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7400 @ 2.80GHz × 2 
OS Type: 32-bit
Disk: 59.3 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the link for minimum system requirement for Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comparing the above specs required with yours, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here: [Should I upgrade to 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456232/should-i-upgrade-to-14-04lts)

Ubuntu 12.04 support ends in April 2017, so you have plenty of time to make a decision. Having said that, let me also add that upgrading to 14.04 LTS Trusty Thar could also help.